# Globally change compile command

Tags: docker, emacs, compilation

I use Emacs for developing with Docker. Emacs runs on the host with a volume containing the code, which gets executed, tested etc. inside of the Docker container.

I started editing some Emacs modes and added variables to allow docker as a command prefix. So with use of `.dir-locals` I am able to run commands like `rspec` inside of the Docker container. But I had to change the code of the `rspec-mode` to get there. All the modes I have seen so long have in common, that they use Emacs' `compile` function to run their commands.

So I wonder if there is any chance to globally expand the `compile` function or anything in comint to add a prefix for running each external command which is started via compile inside of Docker. E.g. `rspec` would be converted to `docker-compose exec app rspec`. Ideally this would be done in a `.dir-locals` to allow project specific prefixes.

This would result in a much more general solution which should work for any mode without need to change their code. It would not be limited to Docker but support any environment, where some modes need a special prefix to their commands.

Unfortunately, I have no idea, how to get something like this running.

Comment: I don't use docker, but it looks like there's a tramp extension for it: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampAndDocker.  Seems like you could open a file or directory in the container and the compile command should automatically run there (like it does with remote machines over ssh).  Also check out multi-compile; I use that to organize compile commands.

Comment: I have not tried Tramp, but as far as I read, it would remove the advantages of editing the files in my local source tree. multi-compile looks interesting, I need to have a further look into this. Another approach was to redefine `compile` to take a prefix which gets added to each command. Here I get the problem, that some extensions use global file paths, which do not exist inside of the Docker container. My next idea is to additionaly add a `.dir-locals` project root variable, which will allow to replace global paths by local ones.

Comment: `compile` runs `make` by default. Can't you do what you need to do by writing an appropriate `Makefile`?

Comment: You don't need to open all of the files with Tramp, just one you run `compile` from.  In fact, you could just define a command to run compile in the container `(let ((default-directory "/docker:user@container:/path/to/source")) (call-interactively #'compile))`.

Comment: @jpkotta But i want to run compile from different files. E.g. in `rspec-mode` I want to be able to run just the spec the cursor is on from inside of the file buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now came up with the following:

In my Emacs initialisation file, I have added some vars and changed the `compile` command as follows:

```
(defvar compilation-command-prefix nil
"Using environments like docker, this can be used to
add a command prefix which is executed before each compile command.
Last given char in most cases should be whitespace.")

(defvar compilation-project-root nil
"When set to a projecet root dir, parameters which contain that dir 
get subsituted, which makes them relative to the root path.")

(defun compile (command &optional comint)
    (interactive
     (list
      (let ((command (eval compile-command)))
        (if (or compilation-read-command current-prefix-arg)
      (compilation-read-command command)
    command))
      (consp current-prefix-arg)))
    (unless (equal command (eval compile-command))
      (setq compile-command command))
    (save-some-buffers (not compilation-ask-about-save)
                       compilation-save-buffers-predicate)
    (setq-default compilation-directory default-directory)
    (compilation-start (concat compilation-command-prefix (replace-regexp-in-string compilation-project-root "" command)) comint))
```

So when `compilation-command-prefix` and `compilation-project-root` are given, the first one is used as prefix for `command` and the second one is removed from `command` to get relative file paths.

The corresponding `.dir-locals.el` is:

```
((nil
  . ((compilation-command-prefix . "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec app ")
     (eval setq compilation-project-root
           (replace-regexp-in-string "~" (getenv "HOME") (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el"))))))
```

This works for me even if some sort of before hook in `compile` would be a more elegant solution.